# Get column number of C construct in ast generated by pycparser

Tags: pycparser

I do know that "coord" attribute of AST node gives the line number but by default it has column number set as None. Is there a way to set this to true column number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `master` branch version on Github, which didn't make it into an official release yet, does include a column in the `coord` attribute of AST nodes.

The `examples/explore_ast.py` example can show this in action, if you uncomment the line with `showcoord=True`. Here's a dumped AST snippet:

```
FileAST:  (at None)
  Typedef: Node, [], ['typedef'] (at <none>:2:17)
    TypeDecl: Node, [] (at <none>:2:17)
      IdentifierType: ['int'] (at <none>:2:13)
  Typedef: Hash, [], ['typedef'] (at <none>:2:23)
    TypeDecl: Hash, [] (at <none>:2:23)
      IdentifierType: ['int'] (at <none>:2:13)
  FuncDef:  (at <none>:4:10)
    Decl: HashPrint, [], [], [] (at <none>:4:10)
      FuncDecl:  (at <none>:4:10)
        ParamList:  (at <none>:4:24)
          Decl: hash, [], [], [] (at <none>:4:24)
            PtrDecl: [] (at <none>:4:24)
              TypeDecl: hash, [] (at <none>:4:26)
```

The `(at <none>:2:17)` part means "at file `<none>`, line 2, column 17" (file is `<none>` because the example is just parsing from a string).